# How to access fields of dyn structs?

Tags: rust, dynamic-dispatch

Recently I've been working on learning advanced Rust. As part of that, I'm learning to use dynamic dispatch.

In my tinkering I've run across a bit of an issue. For some reason, I can't seem to access fields of structs which have been assigned to variables using Boxes and dynamic dispatch. For example,

```
fn main() {
    let z: Box<dyn S>;
    z = Box::new(A::new());

    println!("{}", z.val);
}

trait S {
    fn new () -> Self where Self: Sized;
}


struct A {
    val: i32,
}

impl S for A {
    fn new () -> A {
        A {val: 1}
    }
}

struct B {
    val: i32
}

impl S for B {
    fn new() -> B {
        B {val:2}
    }
}
```

yields the error message "error[E0609]: no field `val` on type `Box<dyn S>`"

Is there any way to access such fields, or do I need to kluge together a workaround?

Comment: There's not a way to do this. And there's no kludge either to trick it. Downcasting was always a nasty hack and the wrong way to do things, and I applaud Rust for ridding itself of that nightmare. A trait object is a thing on which you can do a very small finite number of operations and *nothing* more.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo In that case, what would you recommend that I use instead of dynamic dispatch?

Comment: Since `trait` has no field, so you cannot do this. Alternatively, You may add a method to get such a field in the `trait`, and the `struct` implements that method.

Comment: @TheDaleks That depends a whole lot on what you want to do. Why are you turning your struct into a trait object if you want access to its specifics?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I'm currently working on a Rust port of Super Star Trek. I was hoping to have a Ship trait, which would be implemented for the structs representing the Enterprise and the Faerie Queen (the backup ship). That way, I wouldn't need a lot of extra logic for if a player has to abandon the Enterprise; I could just use the Faerie Queen's struct as a drop-in replacement.

Comment: If you only have two possibilities, then that's an excellent use case for `enum`. An `enum` is like a trait, except there's a finite number of implementors ever, and you're intended to discriminate based on them.

Comment: Note that from a strictly OO perspective you should never access fields from outside the object's methods (either directly or through get/set accessors): [Why getter and setter methods are evil](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2073723/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html).

Answer (score 5):

It is easy to understand why this does not work if you understand what a trait object is. When a method returns a `dyn Trait` it does not return an instance of any `struct`. Instead it returns a lookup table, which tells the caller where to find its methods. So the caller can access methods without knowing anything about underlying `struct` itself.

So if the caller does not have access to the `struct` itself it's clear it cannot access its fields.

There are two ways to implement what you are trying to do:

1. Use methods of the trait to access required fields. This is a good option if the list of possible implementors of the trait is not predetermined, and if the trait itself is not too complex (as traits that can be represented as trait objects have some limitations). Not though that trait objects come with some runtime overhead (using lookup tables is slower then direct method access).
2. Use `enum`. If you know complete list of options that the method can return, it's the best and the most Rust'y solution.

```
enum S {
  A { val: i32, anotherAval: u32 },
  B { val: i32, anotherBval: f32 },
}

impl S {
  fn val(&self) -> i32 {
    match self {
      S::A => A.val,
      S::B => B.val,
    }
  }
}
```